# How can I fill the area where the boundary is given by functions?

Tags: pgfplots

I defined an area bounded by four functions. I found related answers like:
"[filling area between 2 functions, with shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34102/filling-area-between-2-functions-with-shading)", but I am not able to adapt this. solution.

Here the example:

```
% !TEX program  = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
width=10cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={-latex},
clip =false,
xmin=0,xmax=2.45,
ymin=0,
no markers,
xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
every axis x label/.append style={anchor=north},
every axis y label/.append style={anchor=east},
]
\addplot[domain=0.4:1.2,thick] { 1/x } node[anchor=135] {$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$};
\addplot[domain=.6:2,thick] { 2/x } node[right] {$f(x)=\dfrac{2}{x}$};
\addplot[domain=0.7:1.5,thick] { x } node[right] {$f(x)=x$};
\addplot[domain=0.4:.8,thick] { 4*x } node[right] {$f(x)=4x$};


%\addplot+[domain=0.5:1] { 1/x };
%\addplot+[domain=1:sqrt(2)] { x };
%\addplot+[domain=1/sqrt(2):sqrt(2)] { 2/x };
%\addplot+[domain=0.5:1/sqrt(2)] { 4*x };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]

I want to fill the area with vertical lines or maybe simple gray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way.

The environment needs the option `area style` to draw correct axis.

Now I draw every function again with the command closedcycle where the functions above are filled with gray and the functions below fill with white. (draw over).

```
% !TEX program  = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
width=10cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={-latex},
clip =false,
xmin=0,xmax=2.45,
ymin=0,
no markers,
xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
every axis x label/.append style={anchor=north},
every axis y label/.append style={anchor=east},
area style,
]

\addplot+[domain=1/sqrt(2):sqrt(2),fill,gray] { 2/x }  \closedcycle;
\addplot+[domain=0.5:1/sqrt(2),fill,gray] { 4*x }  \closedcycle;
\addplot+[domain=0.5:1,fill,white] { 1/x } \closedcycle;
\addplot+[domain=1:sqrt(2),fill,white] { x }  \closedcycle;

\addplot[domain=0.4:1.2,thick] { 1/x } node[anchor=135] {$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$};
\addplot[domain=.6:2,thick] { 2/x } node[right] {$f(x)=\dfrac{2}{x}$};
\addplot[domain=0.7:1.5,thick] { x } node[right] {$f(x)=x$};
\addplot[domain=0.4:.8,thick] { 4*x } node[right,] {$f(x)=4x$};

\node at (axis cs:1,1.5) {$D$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

tkz-fct  can't answer properly but it's relatively easy to make it with tikz. Before the "clip", I use the macros of tkz-fct to draw the graphs with gnuplot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2,yscale=2,line width=0.6pt,>=latex]
  \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=3] 
  \tkzGrid
  \tkzAxeXY 
  \tkzFct[domain=0.5:2]{2/x}   
  \tkzFct[domain=0.2:1.5]{1/x}  
  \tkzFct[domain=0.2:1]{4*x} 
  \tkzFct[domain=0.5:1.5]{x}  
  \clip (0.5,0) -- plot[domain=0.5:2] function{4*x} -- (2,0)--cycle;
  \clip (0.5,3) -- plot[domain=0.5:2] function{x}   -- (2,3)--cycle;
  \clip (0.5,0) -- plot[domain=0.5:2] function{2/x} -- (2,0)--cycle;
  \clip (0.5,3) -- plot[domain=0.5:2] function{1/x} -- (2,3)--cycle;     
  \fill[blue!20,fill opacity=.5] (0.5,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

With tkz-fct the answer  is shorter for the final steps:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2,yscale=2,line width=0.6pt,>=latex]
  \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=3] 
  \tkzGrid
  \tkzAxeXY 
  \tkzFct[domain=0.5:2]{2/x}   
  \tkzFct[domain=0.2:1.5]{1/x}  
  \tkzFct[domain=0.2:1]{4*x} 
  \tkzFct[domain=0.5:1.5]{x}  
  \clip (0.5,0) -- plot[domain=0.5:2] function{4*x} -- (2,0)--cycle;
  \clip (0.5,3) -- plot[domain=0.5:2] function{x}   -- (2,3)--cycle;  
  \tkzDrawAreafg[between= a and b,color = blue!20,domain = 0.5:1.5]    
\end{tikzpicture}
```