# Shading area with crunch in axis

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

As per a suggestion, I'm splitting my previous (multiple) [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641788/placing-two-graphs-side-by-side-and-shading-the-area-below-a-curve) into separate parts.

I want part of the area below a curve to be shaded, but using a filled rectangle results (of course) in the top part of the crunch to be shaded (when it shoudn't be) and the bottom part not to be shaded (when it should).

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         ticks=none, 
         axis x line=bottom,
         axis y line=left,
         axis y discontinuity=crunch,
         xmin=0,xmax=1.3,
         ymin=0.5,ymax=1.3]
      \addplot[
         domain = 0:sqrt(1/3),
         samples =200,
         ] {sqrt(7/6-x^2)};
      \addplot[
         domain = sqrt(1/3):sqrt(7/6),
         fill = gray,
         fill opacity = 0.1,
         samples =200,
         y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(7/6 )?0:y},
         ] {sqrt(7/6-x^2)}\closedcycle;
      \addplot[
         domain = 0:7,
         samples =200,
         ] {sqrt(5/6)};
      \fill[gray, opacity = 0.1] (0,0) -- (0,0.9129) -- (0.5774,0.9129) -- (0.5774,0);
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: If you need a line to be a plot (`\addplot`), then use `samples=2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ticks=none, 
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
xmin=0, xmax=1.3,
ymin=0.5, ymax=1.3,
y axis line style={name path=yaxis},
]
\addplot[
name path=circ,
domain=0:sqrt(7/6-1/4),
samples=200,
] {sqrt(7/6-x^2)};
\addplot[gray] fill between [of=yaxis and circ, reverse=false, soft clip={(-1,-1) rectangle (1,{sqrt(5/6)})}, on layer={axis background}];
\draw (0,{sqrt(5/6)}) -- (1.3,{sqrt(5/6)});
\draw ({sqrt(1/3)},0.5) -- ({sqrt(1/3)},{sqrt(5/6)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quarter of circle in graph partly filled]

Comment: +1: What is the reverse=false for?

Comment: The default `reverse=auto` fails for some unknown reason resulting in a wrong filling path alike this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641304/why-does-the-filled-area-between-the-curves-get-cut-into-a-x-shape/641308#641308

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply. Should this be reported as a potential bug?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Just looked at the manual again p. 444: "Configures whether the input paths specified by of need to be reversed in order to arrive at a suitable
path concatenation."..."Manual reversal is necessary if pgfplots chose the wrong one.". So it is not guaranteed that `auto` works. -not a bug.

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply!